# How to get a global test coverage for a folder

Tags: unit-testing, go, code-coverage

When showing code coverage, go test show code coverage for each package (in percentage).

Is there a way to show a summary for a folder that is taking all subfolder (subpackage) into account?

What I want is a global code coverage percentage for the full project, one number that show code coverage of the folder and all subfolders.

Comment: No there is not. You need an external tool.

Comment: @Volker: Do you know of any external tool for that ?

Comment: Tool requests are off-topic. But I'm not aware of any command-line tools that do that, but codecov.io will do that, but it's probably overkill for what you're seeking.

Comment: @volker : I'd like to point out that "no there is not" is not an answer, as a matter of fact I did found a way to do it.

Comment: @BlueMagma: The answer you provide actually proves Volker's point. You had to build your own, external tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

I first run the test on all package and store the test result in a file :

```
go test --coverprofile=coverage.out ./...
```

I then run a bash script to calculate my result

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

covered=0
total=0
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< "$line"
    total=$(($total+${array[1]}))
    if [ "${array[2]}" = "1" ]; then
        covered=$(($covered+${array[1]}))
    fi 
done < "$1"
echo $(awk "BEGIN { pc=100*${covered}/${total}; i=int(pc); print (pc-i<0.5)?i:i+1 }")
```

Comment: Have you try *go test --coverprofile=coverage.out -coverpkg=./your/package/... ./your/package*. Notice that you need to specific the test run for just your root package not all (./...)

Comment: What is that script doing?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari it seems it does a similar job to what is described in details in the 3rd part of this article that I found interesting : https://eleni.blog/2021/01/10/test-coverage-in-go-working-with-packages-and-sub-packages/

Answer (score 8):

After running:

```
go test --coverprofile=coverage.out ./...
```

Run:

```
go tool cover -func=coverage.out
```

You will see the total percentage at the end of the result

Comment: you got to create a ***_test.go file for each ***.go file you have with the package declaration even if you don't have any tests for that given file. Otherwise your metrics will not consider the file with no test and the cover percentage will not reflect your project.

Answer (score -1):

You can have the coverage of all sub-packages without any external tools/ with:

```
go test --coverprofile=coverage.out -coverpkg=./your/package/... ./your/package
```

> ```
> -coverpkg pattern1,pattern2,pattern3
>     Apply coverage analysis in each test to packages matching the patterns.
>     The default is for each test to analyze only the package being tested.
>     See 'go help packages' for a description of package patterns.
>     Sets -cover.
> ```

https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Testing_flags